# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException' - Cannot Find A Solution

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have built an app from a tutorial. The pages went to and from each other with no problems using modal segue. However, I add the main content (calling values from a plist) and when I run the main quiz page, i get this error:

```
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: >'[<QuizViewController 0x719e9b0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value >coding-compliant for the key lblQuestionA.'
>*** First throw call stack:
>(0x1c90012 0x10cde7e 0x1d18fb1 0xb7a711 0xafbec8 0xafb9b7 0xb26428 0x2320cc 0x10e1663
>0x1c8b45a 0x230bcf 0xf5e37 0xf6418 0xf6648 0xf6882 0x102235 0x3013d2 0xff4f3 0xff777 0xff7b7 
>0x46afe2 0x45cad9 0x45cb54 0x10e1705 0x18920 0x188b8 0xd9671 0xd9bcf 0xd8d38 0x4833f 0x48552 
>0x263aa 0x17cf8 0x1bebdf9 0x1bebad0 0x1c05bf5 0x1c05962 0x1c36bb6 0x1c35f44 0x1c35e1b >0x1bea7e3 0x1bea668 0x1565c 0x20dd 0x2005)
>libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
>(lldb)
```

Any ideas why?

Thanks!

Comment: Because you tagged this question as `xcode`.

Comment: It looks like you are calling `[qvc lblQuestionA]` where `qvc` is an instance of QuizViewController, which does not respond to that selector.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to set a value to `lblQuestionA`, which your `QuizViewController` doesn't implement a setter for.

Maybe you are setting the value on the wrong object, or you are just missing the setter method - without any code (and question, actually) this is hard to answer.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing you have changed the name of IBOutlet variable/property in your source code, but in the corresponding interface builder file you still have it trying to attach to the old name. If you have a interface builder file for this View Controller, check its interface builder file for links to the outlet lblQuestionA, and remove the link and reconnect it to the correct IBOutlet. Its also possible that you have a view element that is connected to two IBOutlets, lblQuestionA and the correct one.